# Best practices to handle TCP and UDP communication to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a project requirements to handle TCP and UDP communications from a device to AWS.

Currently the basic architecture design I've made wasdevice -> Network Load Balancers -> Servers (EC2 Instances). Docker containerization was not used in EC2 instance for server deployment and setup. I use a simple Github Actions -> SSH -> Update servers, since the server code is not that complex.

I was wondering if its possible to use API Gateways for TCP requests (Device does not actually uses HTTP/S), and trigger lambdas so I could remove EC2 instances, but I'm not sure how could I do it with UDP.

Previously the device was communicating via AWS IOT / MQTT and due to battery constraints, the device was force to route traffic securely from the Telcos VPN to AWS via TCP/UDP